# MUI : TextField autofill not working when selecting multiline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When setting a TextField to multiline I'm losing autofill suggestions from my browser (using chrome). If I use standard TextField it works well.

Any idea of why it could happen ?

This is the code working :

```
 <TextField
              {...field}
              style={{ width: "300px" }}
              error={!!errors?.note}
              helperText={errors?.note?.message}
              // multiline
              // autoComplete="day_note"
              maxRows={3}
              sx={{
                "& .MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error": {
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: "100%",
                },
              }}
              label={"Note"}
              variant="outlined"
            />
```

and this is the code not working (I tried with and without the 'autoComplete' field, but it doesn't change any thing :

```
 <TextField
              {...field}
              style={{ width: "300px" }}
              error={!!errors?.note}
              helperText={errors?.note?.message}
              multiline
              autoComplete="day_note"
              maxRows={3}
              sx={{
                "& .MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error": {
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: "100%",
                },
              }}
              label={"Note"}
              variant="outlined"
            />
```